# OpenVPN CENTOS 6.6

Tags: redes, centos, vpn

Tengo que realizar una configuración a un servidor CentOS6.6 para realizar una vpn.

La idea sería poder conectarme a la maquina CentOS por un vpn.

He intentado realizarlo con tutoriales que he encontrado como este: 
https://blog.cike.ws/2017/04/20/openvpn-centos-6-9/
Pero no lo consigo.

¿Alguna ayuda o guía para poder realizarlo?
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Jorge, primero lee el [tour]. Luego revisa esta guía __[ask]__. A continuación, te platico que la guía que elegiste está muy bien hecha, no hay otra forma de levantar OpenVPN, así que algo estás haciendo mal. Revisa dos o tres veces cada paso para asegurarte que estás haciéndolo bien. Por último, este es una comunidad de programadores, no precisamente de informática, así que tal vez tu pregunta sea cerrada porque __no es posible reproducir tu error__ o errores.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no es un problema relacionado con la temática del sitio.

Comment: Lo siento, me revisare el recorrido y como preguntar. Pensaba que también podría preguntar esto, tomo nota, gracias!